# Ordering Dimension Hierarchy SSAS

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, dimension

I'm quite new to SSAS so bear with me!

I have created a snowflake schema with Members in the Fact table and I have create a distance from club table with DistanceID,Distance,DistanceRange (this is denormalised in SQL Server with distance range appearing multiple times per distance. e.g Distance 1 has a range of 1 - 10 and Distance 2 also has a range of 1 - 10

I have then created a hierarchy with Distance Range at the top and Distance beneath it. This works OK in terms of providing drill down functionality but the ordering is wrong for distance range. It is ordering them by Distance Range as a string so I get 1-10 followed by 100-10 and then 20-30.

How do I tell the Distance Range to order by Distance ID

Not sure if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score -1):

When you are editing your Dimension, click on the attribute DistanceRange and in the properties, there should be an option to 'OrderBy' and 'OrderByAttribute'. Try and use those the get the result you need. Otherwise, you might want to try change the 'Type' in the properties menu and see if that works.

Comment: Yes I tried that but the OrderByAttribute is empty for DistanceRange. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Nope. I have a similar problem in a time dimension and that is another question unanswered so no idea what else it could be.

Comment: What I did was ordering by key which is in the correct order. Total hack but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: in what do you display? in ssas itself or something like excel, powerpivot or ssrs?

Comment: At the momment I'm using bids then the next step is getting it working devexpresses pivot grid

Comment: Just something to remember if it gives the same problem in excel, powerpivot and or ssrs you will need to cast is again or else it will sort as text again even though it is correct in bids.

Comment: What do you mean cast again

Comment: In the case we had, the time displayed correctly in bids, but when it was displayed in excel, powerp or ssrs, it sorted the time as text, the guy that used it, fixed it by creating a calculated field of that field and casting it as int, and used the calculated field instead.